# replace start-of-line value of a csv file

Tags: powershell

Hi I need a little help

I need to change the first value of the first column of a csv

```
"A"; "B"; "C"; "D"
"1"; Rome";" Italy";"12/1/2023"
"2"; "Milan";"Italy";"2/11/2023"
"3"; "Firneze"; "Italy";"13/3/2021"
```

Riuslt

```
"A"; "B"; "C"; "D"
"one"; Rome";" Italy";"12/1/2023"
"two"; "Milan";"Italy";"2/11/2023"
"three"; "Firneze"; "Italy";"13/3/2021"
```

using the replace command obviously also changes the date

```
-replace '1' , 'one'
```

this is the wrong result

```
"A"; "B"; "C"; "D"
"one"; Rome";" Italy";"12/one/2023"
```

you can help me?

Questo è il file csv originario

```
"cycle";"support";"eol";"latest";"releaseDate";"OS"
"9";"2027-05-31";"2027-05-31";"9";"2021-09-15";"Centos"
"stream-8";"2024-05-31";"2024-05-31";"8";"2019-09-24";"Centos"
"8";"2021-12-31";"2021-12-31";"8 (2111)";"2019-09-24";"Centos"
"7";"2020-08-06";"2024-06-30";"7 (2009)";"2014-07-07";"Centos"
"6";"2017-05-10";"2020-11-30";"6.10";"2011-07-10";"Centos"
```

Questo è quello di cui ho bisogno

```
"cycle";"support";"eol";"latest";"releaseDate";"OS"
"Release 9.";"2027-05-31";"2027-05-31";"9";"2021-09-15";"Centos"
"Release stream 8.";"2024-05-31";"2024-05-31";"8";"2019-09-24";"Centos"
"Release 8.";"2021-12-31";"2021-12-31";"8 (2111)";"2019-09-24";"Centos"
"Release 7.";"2020-08-06";"2024-06-30";"7 (2009)";"2014-07-07";"Centos"
"Release 6.";"2017-05-10";"2020-11-30";"6.10";"2011-07-10";"Centos"
```

Answer (score 1):

import the CSV by using `import-csv`, by doing so you get an array of objects back and so you can simply target only the property you want to update, e.g.

```
#load csv
$csv = import-csv [path] -delimiter ";"

#loop and set value of property cycle
$csv | %{
    $_.cycle = 'Release ' + $_.cycle
}

#output new csv to file
$csv | export-csv [path]
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand if I have to write my needs again or if I made a mistake in commenting on your answer

Comment: I'll updated the code to reflect the real csv and requirements

Comment: @renato cilento then please accept the answer :-)